What is known about $\operatorname{gap}(A) = \|A\| - r(A)$ for bounded operators on Hilbert spaces?
The gap of a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space is defined as $$\operatorname{gap}(A) := \|A\| - r(A),$$
where $r(A)$ denotes the spectral radius of $A$. A natural question to ask is - for which operators is $\operatorname{gap}(A) > 0$ (vs. $\operatorname{gap}(A) = 0$)? A simple but not satisfying fact is that $\operatorname{gap}(A) = 0$ for all normal operators $A$. Even after a detailed search, I could find just one paper that studies gaps to some extent (here.)
Thanks!

I think you need to consider related operators $B = S^{-1}AS$, where $S$ is invertible.  The spectral radius for $B$ is the same as for $A$, but the norm may be different.  I believe (I read somewhere long ago?) the infimum of all these norms is the spectral radius.

Notice that a nilpotent operator $A$ has $r(A) = 0,$ whereas $|A|$ can be arbitrarily large, so I wonder what sort of answer you would regard as useful in your context?
